# How to make a ISO file out of a folder containing Windows 7 setup files

Tags: windows-7

I copied the Windows 7 image from a USB Bootable device to my HDD. I want to convert that folder to an ISO and use that to create a bootable USB.

Please tell me how I can make an ISO image out of that folder containing files.

Comment: You can use ImgBurn utility for it. you can download it from here: https://download.cnet.com/ImgBurn/3000-2646_4-10847481.html or look on that topic too: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/create-your-own-iso-file-from-a-windows-7/a344df19-b535-4420-a58f-4898ac7416ec

Comment: @VEGA that seems like an answer to me... why don't you post it as one. :) welcome to SuperUser Descope.

Comment: @Stese I kept away from it because i were near to ban for answer before and i do not want to be banned. :))))

Answer (score 1):

Creating a bootable ISO can be done using the free ImgBurn utility:

- Download [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/index.php?act=download)
- Install while skipping all bloatware offers
- Start and install and choose the option of *Create image file from files/folders*
- In the *Source* section, browse to the folder that contains the installation files
- Set the destination to the path where you want to create the ISO file
- In the *Advanced* tab click on the option *Bootable Disc*
- select *Make Image Bootable*
- Choose *Emulation type* as *None (Custom)*
- Type `8` in the box next to *Sectors To Load*
- Click on the browse icon next to the *Extract Boot Image* and select the
  file `etfsboot.com` from the installation files
- Click the *Build* icon and wait for it to finish. Once the ISO file has been successfully created.

You may also use ImgBurn to burn the ISO to a DVD or a USB Drive.